# Running Maven2 and Maven3

Tags: java, maven

I am currently building a new server to replace our existing live system and taking the oppertunity to bring all the systems up to date. Unfortunately we will need to run the two systems as live services in parallel for several months before the switch is finalised. During this time we will be running nightly rebuilds as development of the applications running on the servers is ongoing.

The problem I am running into is that the existing system is running Maven 2 and the new System is running Maven 3. Currently our rebuilds to the new server are generating Maven warnings ("[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin is missing") and the applications fail to build.

Is there a solution to allow me to fix these warnings such that everything will build on both Maven 2 and Maven 3? Due to the development infrastructure branching the code within subversion isn't an option.

Looking at some of the documentation it suggests moving the repository definitions to be pluginrepository definitions. Can I add the repositories into pluginrepositories whilst leaving them under repositories and will this cause an issue with either version of Maven? Or is there an alternative solution to the problem?

Comment: Warnings don't break a build. Seems you are not mentioned something.

Comment: @kan completely missing Maven plugins will break a build, they are akin to missing tasks in ANT, or missing command line tools in Make.

Comment: @EdwinBuck He says about warning "version tag is missing", it means that plugin is here, it works, but pom.xml doesn't explicitly specifies plugin version, so a random version is used. And then he tells that it fails to build - I don't believe it could happen because of it.

Comment: @kan If the version tag is missing, then odds are he configured some older versions of plugins, which now are running in their "upgraded" releases.  Upgrades can break things, especially if you were configuring your plugins through now-deprecated tags.

Comment: @EdwinBuck But is not maven-version specific. Why just running another version of the maven makes the difference?

Comment: @kan Maven runs plugins, which have their own versions.  If the plugin is upgraded without the upgrade being backwards compatible, it will break.  Naturally Maven2 doesn't pull Maven3 plugins, and no version was specified to keep the plugins at Maven2 levels, so Maven3 will just pull the "latest" copy of the plugin.  Viola! Instant plugin upgrades, and possible breakage.

Answer (score 0):

Maven 3 is backwards compatible, but stricter, so if you fix the pom.xml for Maven 3, you will not break Maven 2 support.

From what I read, you only have to use explicit Plugin Versions, and that can easily be done, a best practice would be to do it in a [`<pluginManagement>`](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) section in a parent pom common to the projects.

Comment: There are some things that Maven 3 does differently enough that if you tailor your POM for Maven 3, a Maven 2 build *may* break. One thing that's different is the way dependencies are resolved. I found that to build in Maven 2 I had to add several `dependency`s that were not required in Maven 3.

Comment: another issue is with the unique version of snapshot changes in maven 3. you might have some issues there if you need to deploy snapshot artifact which are in turn used by other artifacts. i still can't figure out why they changed it. brings more trouble than anything, mostly in continuous builds with multiple projects.